# Diamond-question-marks in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, fonts, thin-client

I'm running Visual Studio 2005 for the first time on my new machine (an HP thin client accessing a virtual machine over their [HP SAM Client](http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/cache/323204-0-0-225-121.html?jumpid=ex_r2548_go/sam/kimsmb/2H07Collateral/062607) software). When execution halts on an exception, the text for that line appears as below. It appears that it can't find the characters in some font variant or something, but I can't figure it out.

I tried changing the font from Courier New to other ones, and it made no difference. This same character showed up in that alternate font. I wasn't even sure what to try searching for on here or Google with this one.

**Update:** I'm seeing this in various other places in my code, even at design-time. It definitely appears linked to some specific font attribute, though I haven't been able to tell which.

**Update 2:** I'm not sure whether this is surprising or not, but copying and pasting the question marks into another application works as though there's no problem.

**Update 3:** On the same machine, Visual Studio 2008 behaves as expected (that is to say, normally). To provide additional details on VS2005, I'm running version 8.0.5727.42.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to [Visual Studio 2005 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en) fixed this bug. Our default installation is an outdated version.